# CSS hover not overwriting REACT state inline props

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have images that stack over each others by 15 pixels.
Since they come from an array I use inline css with react state to give them the z-index level.
I'm not sure it's needed but I believe it's good practice.

This is the React/HTML image element

```
 {val.pairs.map((a,x) => <img key={a} attr={x} style={{zIndex: val.pairs.length - i}} alt{val}/> )}
```

Now if I use some css to bring it above the next one;

```
 img:hover{
  z-index: 99;
  border:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

The border get applied but not the z-index.

I think it is because it's hooked to the state. Now React keep bugging me when I forget my key attribute in a list. How do I use that key to update the z-index of that element?

Comment: So, a cheap way I think may work, is to add a class to the hovered Element in the elements onhover and reset the zindex in the new class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is not the react or state, this comes basically from css and how it calculates specificity of css rules. Inline styles always are stronger than regular css by selector, so only way to overwrite it - use `!important`.

```
  z-index: 99 !important;
```

You may check this article if you are interested of how it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Here is a simple example for it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cherry-xvg6w?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I would love it if it was that simple. But it doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a sandbox with not working example, please?

Comment: Not really. But i removed the inline style attribute and still deosn't work. so the plain css :hover isn't picking up z-index

Comment: Are you sure that :hover event actually fired but css is not picked up?
You may force `hover` state using chrome inspector under styles -> :hov button. Please, make sure when you force your image with :hover state the css is not picked up. Otherwise it seems like event cant be fired because of layers, or something else...

Comment: The border is working. So hover in plain css do work. just not z-index. it's not even within the state. just plain css

Comment: Please, check this example https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cherry-xvg6w?file=/src/App.js
Is this similar to your case?

Comment: I think this is way better answer. and you have it workin. You should really add it to the answer